# Validation in domain model?

Tags: validation, domain-driven-design

I've designed a domain model following DDD methodology. I would like to add validation.

Do you think adding validation at the domain model level is a good idea? If no, where should I validate my domain objects?

Thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If the validation rules form part of the business domain, they belong *in* the model.

An aggregate root is responsible of maintaining the invariants encompassed by it, so validating them falls under its responsibility.

If you find that the validation rules are very complex, you can create a validation service that will be used by the aggregate root for this function.

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. As you said, business rules should be checked at the domain level, and generally by the aggregate roots. What about the trivial validation rules? For example, a Customer entity has a name that can't be null. Where to check that?

Comment: @MickaelMarrache - Is this a business rule in your bounded context? Yes? Then it belongs in the domain. Something like this should probably be enforced by the `Customer` entity directly.

Comment: I agree if you. Validating business domain rules belongs into the business domain layer. Validating user inputs from a GUI can also be handled in the GUI directly (for performance reason) or the persistency layer.

Comment: *"For example, a Customer entity has a name that can't be null. Where to check that?"* - Write your `Customer` class in such a way that it's impossible to instantiate a customer without a valid name. Demand a name in the constructor, and do not allow people to override that value with a null.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on the kind of validation you have.

If it's just that a Customer name is required and that there is a maximum length for a field, then it's not the responsibility of the domain itself. This should be input validation.

If you are creating a webshop and the Order is invalid when not all items are in stock, then you have some real domain validation.

[Domain Driven Design 101](http://www.slideshare.net/rdingwall/domain-driven-design-101) has some nice examples starting at slide 44.

Answer (score 3):

Seealso: http://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2009/02/15/validation-in-a-ddd-world.

"Instead of answering the question, “is this object valid”, try and answer the question, “Can this operation be performed?”."